# Complex product with unknown number results in a given modulus

Tags: complex-numbers

I have the following complex number $ z = (40-9i)·(a+7i) $ and I want to find the number $ a $ such that $ \left| z \right| = 1025 $

I tried to solve it through a couple of methods such as developing $ z $ to represent the product, try to isolate $ a $, try to put the modulus formula in an equation-like fashion but I'm stuck in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|z|=|(40-9i)(a+7i)|=|40-9i||a+7i|=41|a+7i|=1025$$
$$\therefore |a+7i|=25 \implies a=\pm 24$$

Comment: In "polar form" we can write the two numbers as $a_1e^{i\theta}_1$ and $a_2e^{\theta_2}$ where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are the moduli of the two complex numbers and $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are the "arguments" so that the product is $(a_1a_2)e^{i(\theta_1+ \theta_2)}$.  That clearly has modulus $a_1a_2$.  That is why Peter Foreman can just multiply the two moduli.

Answer (score 0):

Well:
$$(40-9i)(a+7i)=(40a+63)+(280-9a)i$$
So:
$$1025^2=(40a+63)^2+(280-9a)^2$$
This is just a quadratic.

Comment: What's the problem with this answer?

Comment: $\pm 1025= 40a +63\implies \pm 962= 40a\implies \pm 481= 20a\implies a= \pm 24.5$.

Comment: @jiten Where did you get $\pm 1025=40a+63$? Did you miss the $(280-9a)^2$? It's easy albeit a little tedious to expand the whole thing and solve the quadratic resulting to get $a=\pm 24$